# Create multiple selection options and go back options on ruby cli app

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface

I am trying to build a ruby CLI application and I want my user to select from a certain amount of options that I provide him with.
Remember: This is not a ruby on rails app and there is no views or anything. It is one file of ruby code that I intend to create which  shall be responsive to whatever the user types.

When a user runs the script. He should be able to see 3 options and should be able to select them and each of these should have different implications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple approach without any additional gem might be:

```
puts "Choose an option"
puts "1 – Option 1"
puts "2 – Option 2"
# ...

case gets.chomp.to_i
when 1
  puts "run code for option 1"
when 2
  puts "run code for option 2"
# ...
else
  puts "invalid option"
end
```

Comment: Hey man! A big thanks for this. Really worked! I would like to know if you can tell me how to create a back option further? You know, like there should always be a button on my cli which takes them to this selection section again, kinda like a 'Back' button.